# Get Current Post ID in WP Loop For GiveWP

Tags: plugins, shortcode, id

How to get current ID for WP Loop in my case?

I try to loop the GIVEWP (Success), then I try to echo shortcode of GOAL Progress Bar of GiveWP but the problem is, i don't know how to get the current ID.

Here my code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- LOOP -->
<?php echo do_shortcode('[give_goal id="INEEDCURRENTIDHERE" show_text="true" show_bar="true"]'); ?>
<!-- END LOOP -->
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Get current id in while loop **$id = get_the_id();** then use id in shortcode like
**do_shortcode('[give_goal id="'.$id.'" show_text="true" show_bar="true"]');**

Comment: Thanks @ChetanVaghela . It's works! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try using this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

> OR

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

> OR

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```